# Which file system is supported by both OS X and Windows and can handle large files?

Tags: windows, mac, filesystems

I want to store large files (up to 50GB for a single file) on an external hard drive. Both Mac OS X and Windows 7 need to be able to read and write to the hard drive. Additionally, I want to use the drive as a Time Machine backup location.
Which file system do I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Time Machine on same disk containing Windows files](http://superuser.com/questions/168741/run-time-machine-on-same-disk-containing-windows-files) also see [which harddrive format do i use for both mac and windows to write/read?](http://superuser.com/questions/149577/which-harddrive-format-do-i-use-for-both-mac-and-windows-to-write-read?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless its changed recently, Time Machine requires a HFS+ formatted volume to function.  Windows can not read or write HFS+ natively, however [Paragon's HFS+ for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/download.html) is highly rated and not expensive ($20 US).

So if you *have* to set it up the way you described, you will need to format the drive for HFS+ and get software for Windows to read/write to it.

Comment: I tried that software just now, unfortunately it failed with "Access Denied" when I try to copy something in Windows.